# "Mixing of GROUP columns .. with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause"

Tags: mysql, sql

I am developing a software on Visual Studio 2012 with C#. I am using MySQL Connector 6.9.1 for MySQL connection. My software is working smooth on my OS (Win8 x64), but it is not working on Win7 (on VMWare, I must try it on Win7)

İt is throw this exception:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause

This is my code:

```
      MySqlCommand komut = new MySqlCommand();
        komut.Connection = baglan;
        komut.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        komut.CommandText = "SELECT count(*),yetki FROM kullanicilar WHERE kadi=@kadi AND sifre=@sifre";
        komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kadi", txtKadi.Text);
        komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sifre", txtSifre.Text);
        MySqlDataReader oku = komut.ExecuteReader();
        oku.Read();
        if (oku.GetInt32(0) > 0)
        {

            if (oku.GetString("yetki") == "0")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Hesabınız aktif değil.","Hesap Deaktif",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                baglan.Close();
                return;
            }

            RandevulariYonet randPenc = new RandevulariYonet(txtKadi.Text, this);
            this.Hide();
            randPenc.ShowDialog();

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Giriş Başarsız", "Giriş Başarısız", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

        }
```

Comment: The odd thing is, in MySQL, (while it maybe impractical and/or illogical) this isn't illegal. Ahh, your server has only full group by mode enabled - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the SQL-Statement:

```
SELECT count(*),yetki 
FROM kullanicilar 
WHERE kadi=@kadi AND sifre=@sifre
```

You use `count(*)` and another column, without grouping it. It should look like this:

```
SELECT count(*),yetki 
FROM kullanicilar 
WHERE kadi=@kadi AND sifre=@sifre 
GROUP BY yetki
```